# Could not find member 'CellForItemAtIndexPath'

Tags: ios, swift

Let me describe my problem.

I wrote a Class Called `CardCell` which inherited from `UICollectionViewCell`.
 In my other class, `MainViewController`, a subclass of `UICollectionView`. An instance of NSMutableArray, `items`, was created to store every single cell's data.

var items =  NSMutableArray()

self.items = NSMutableArray(capacity: 20)
   for i in 0...20 {
       items.addObject("Item (i)")
   }

Moving `items` to CollectionView's indexPath and ready to be called.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, moveItemAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    var thing: NSString = items[fromIndexPath.item] as NSString
    self.items.removeObjectAtIndex(fromIndexPath.item)
    self.items.insertObject(thing, atIndex: toIndexPath.item)
}
```

Finally, I'm trying to create an instance of `CardCell` with the `items`.

```
var cell: CardCell = CardCell(self.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(self.collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems().first))
```

Next, an error occurred with "**Could not find member 'CellForItemAtIndexPath'**". **One thing I need to say is those code were translated from an Objective-C version.**

The Objective-C Version:

```
 PassCell *cell = (PassCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] firstObject]];
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

A great appreciation for your guide and time.

Ethan Joe

Comment: have you mentioned `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in delegates

Comment: @Shruti, do you mean `UICollectionViewDelegate` ? Where is the need of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` ??

Comment: I had a similar issue once. I added this delegate and it got resolved. So give it a try.

Comment: @Ethan, Please add code related to collectionview delegates method !!

Comment: Thanks! You mean add `delegate method` in the `CardCell` or `MainViewController`?

Comment: The thing is the author of ObjC Version did not write `UICollectionViewDelegate` in the interface of `MainViewController`'s Header File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something went awry with the translation from Objective-C. I don't think you can use a `UICollectionView` instance method to initialize your custom cell.

In the Objective-C code, you cast the result to the custom cell type. I believe in Swift you should do the same (note that I split the statement into two to improve readability):

```
let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems().first as IndexPath
var cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CardCell
```

Note: depending on your definitions you might need `as?` or `as!` for the cast operator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is another error occur in the second line of your answer. Complier said that '?' which is behind 'self.collectionView' need to be deleted because of `type is (UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ( )`

Comment: After I corrected it as `var cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath as NSIndexPath)`, it built and ran successfully.

Comment: I added the cast for `indexPath` to the first statement. Thanks for pointing out that detail.